# Running "Internet Download Manager" via wine crashes

Tags: 14.04, wine, playonlinux

1. I have installed `wine-1.7.22`
2. Then installed `play on linux` too, which uses `wine`
3. Then I installed `Internet Download Manager 5.17` using `play on linux`
4. It installed successfully, I opened it and ADD URL to it
5. The download window appears
6. Click start download
7. The download crashed but main IDM window keep running
8. Tried resuming but same problem

Anyone know how to fix, or I am missing something. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version 64 bit.

Comment: try launching it in a console and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/303127) your answer with the errors you get. Also, if you are looking for a download manager for linux, you should have a look at `JDownloader`, which is developped in java and thus does not need wine.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work in wine:

<sup>[Source](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=13685)</sup>

```
What works:
Installing and adding a new download url.

What does not:
Downloading, internet connection test at startup
```

Comment: Hey Tim, it would be nice if could answer in English instead of using this encrypted language.
How to get downloading working?

Comment: I did say - `This doesn't work in wine:`. I think that's english. Then I said what does and doesn't work, for clarification i.e. you can install but not download. Try using a download manager for Ubuntu - like `JDownloader`?

Comment: Please remove your answer, its totally irrelevant what question is?Question was not what works and what doesn't?If you have suggestions simple put those in comment boxes, like Ploutox did.

Comment: I have just told you that there is no way you can get it working. I then kindly explained why that was. It does answer the question. `Anyone know how to fix` - no, it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use IDM on Linux OS for two reasons:
1. It's not free, and you'll need to pay for it or use a pirated one;
2. It doesn't comes for Linux, so you'll need to use wine for that purpose;
so that's it. Now there's an another app for downloading, which is meant for ubuntu, and you can download it for free from it's official site in .deb;
the link to it is: [www.flareget.com](http://www.flareget.com)  it's just like IDM and works well + it comes with an youtube handle, which allows you to download videos from the site. So use it, it's an IDM for Linux :)

Comment: Superb, it works great. UI is totally same like IDM.